# Is there a way to pull only the entries in a specific range in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database that already has a lot of data in it and we need to be able to pull entries based on the dates they were added. Is there a way to pull only the entries that were added between for instance January 1, 2018 and January 7, 2018?

Comment: Can you provide some information about the structure of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use this query:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("times");
ref.orderByChild("date").startAt("2018-01-01").endAt("2018-01-07");
```

example if you have this:

```
times
  pushid
   date:2018-01-01
  pushid
   date: 2018-01-07
```

Comment: This did work, but our queries are still running very slowly. Is there a way to speed up the query itself? Or sort through the data quicker?

Comment: maybe optimize the database more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768084/querying-on-firebase-database-with-large-data-set-is-very-very-slow, or ask it as a question with more information provided